# How to resolve Can't resolve all parameters error on angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Just started out with angular 2, and encounter my first error. I am trying to create a service for fetching data from a server but am getting this error

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for CourseService: (?). at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (http:……}

this is the service code throwing the error app/courses/courses.service.ts

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

export class CourseService {

    private  _courses : Object[];

    public get courses() : Object[] {
        return this._courses;
    }

    public set courses(v : Object[]) {
        this._courses = v;
    }

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").subscribe(data => {
            this._courses = data.json();
        });
    }
}
```

this service is supposed to be used in app/courses/courses.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { CourseService } from "app/courses/course.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    providers: [CourseService],
    templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./courses.component.css'] 
})

export class CoursesComponent {
    title : string = "The title of the Course";
    courses : Object[];

    constructor(private courseService: CourseService) {
        console.log("hello");
        this.courses = courseService.courses;
    }
}
```

and app.module contains

```
....
....
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesComponent }  from './courses/courses.component';
import { CourseService } from "./courses/course.service";

@NgModule({
     declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       CoursesComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [CourseService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, CoursesComponent]
})
 export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: update the post with your import statements for this service accross your application?(all components and services if any)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put @Injectable() before export class .
[@Injectable() lets Angular know that a class can be used with the dependency injector.](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/di/angular2/inject_and_injectable.html)